# Отсутствуют некоторые переводы в footer-е сайта

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Отметил части где отсутствует перевод.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил переводы для существующих строк (любой участник сайта может также предложить свою версию перевода!):

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14966
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14977
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14970
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14632

Переводы должны появиться в числе нескольких следующих сборок. Текущая rev 2020.7.30.37309.

По поводу разделов сайтов по тематикам - вопрос о том нужно ли это вообще разрешать переводить подвешен в воздухе уже почти три года: [Localization for footer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299446/339911)